# What is wrong with this sort syntax that gives me the "sort reference not valid"?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

My macro combines two sheets and cleans them up for further processing.  I keep getting the  "sort reference not valid" error at the sort statement.  I have tried many of the methods here to no avail. Can someone please suggest a correction?  I am a hamfisted programmer and I know there are other ways to handle data sets but:

```
'iterate worksheet to delete column A - size sorter / delete all rows without a quantity / sort columns
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim chkcell As String
 Dim lastrow As Long

For Each MmasterWS In MmasterWB.Worksheets
    MmasterWS.Range("A:A").Delete ' delete column A - size sorter
    
    lastrow = MmasterWS.Range("B" & MmasterWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    MmasterWS.Range("A4:O" & lastrow).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 'change all rows to white
    
    For Each rng In MmasterWS.Range("B3:O" & lastrow) 'iterates data range to find empty rows
        
        If lastrow = 3 Then 'sorts sheet by vendor first then harm code. iterates to next sheet in workbook
            
            lastrow = MmasterWS.Range("B" & MmasterWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            MmasterWS.Range("A3:O" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Columns(3), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Columns(14), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            
            GoTo skip2
        
        Else
            
            chkcell = MmasterWS.Range("A" & lastrow).Value 
                If chkcell = "" Then
                    MmasterWS.Range("A" & lastrow).EntireRow.Delete 'deletes empty rows
                End If
                lastrow = lastrow - 1 'moves up one row
        
        End If
     Next

skip2:
Next
```

Tried many suggestions on Stackoverflow.  Any help is appreciated.
Kevin

Comment: First of all, you really need to qualify which `Worksheet`.

Comment: Do you need `MmasterWS.` in front of `Columns(3)` in your key? There are suggestions that it needs qualifying where `Columns(3)` is coming from...

Comment: It didn't error that time but it also didn't sort.  Thanks for the input, I can at least keeping trying things to get it to sort.

Comment: @KjS99: I assume you also put the prefix on key2? I admit I didn't spot that the first time I looked!

Comment: Try `With MmasterWS.Range("A3:O" & LastRow): .Sort Key1:=.Columns(3), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Columns(14), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes: End With`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue.  Thank you Nick for the syntax correction.  Here is how I fixed it:

```
lastrow = MmasterWS.Range("B" & MmasterWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With MmasterWS.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=MmasterWS.Range("N4:N" & lastrow), Order:=xlAscending
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=MmasterWS.Range("C4:C" & lastrow), Order:=xlAscending
            .SetRange MmasterWS.Range("A3:N" & lastrow)
            .Header = xlYes
            .Apply
        End With
```

Comment: In fairness, I think that is what @BigBen meant in his first comment - to clarify which worksheet the key was from. I just didn't understand that at first.

Comment: I concur Nick, I didn't get it at first also.  Also, I was trying to use Columns and I believe the actual syntax is Range("C4:C100")